# create hidden file to windows remote share

Tags: linux, mount, chmod

my user uid is 1000, windows 10 has ntfs FS, from linux executing:

```
mount -t cifs //win-ip/share1 /home/user/remote-dir -o,username=XXX,password=XXX,uid=1000,gid=1000
```

I can write, read and executing files on remote dir, unfortunately If I create a hidden file:

```
touch /home/user/remote-dir/.hidden1
```

from linux works but on windows I see

```
.hidden1
```

and:

```
ls -la

-rwxr-xr-x  1 user user    0 Mar  6 14:28 .hidden

lsattr

----ia----jI--------- .hidden
```

it's normal, but how can I create a hidden file from linux?
also chmod does not effect

Comment: What file system has the remote share? FAT or NTFS?

Comment: I updated my question, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> This is tested locally, Linux Mint 20.1, Windows 10.

You need `ntfs-3g` (The attribute `system.ntfs_attrib_be` only exists since `ntfs-3g-2010.5.22AC.5`).

```
# Set the NTFS hidden flag to file target-file (any computer)
setfattr -h -v 0x00000002 -n system.ntfs_attrib_be target-file
```

---

In my test I could successfully set the hidden flag of a file in a NTFS partition using this method.

---

Source: [Using Extended Attributes](https://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/extend-attr.html)